# Problems understanding iterators and operator overload in c++

Tags: c++, templates, iterator

We have a class example and I just don't get it.  I don't quite understand how the operator() works in this case, and everything starting with sort.  I looked at the output after running the program, and I don't see how those values are obtained.

```
sort indices array: 2 8 10 4 1 7 5 3 0 9 6 11
replay numbers array: 37 33 29 36 32 35 39 34 30 38 31 40
number array via indices 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40
```

I tried looking up functors on this board since the title is functor example, but I guess I don't see how functors are in play here.  Any thoughts would be GREATLY appreciated as I am COMPLETELY lost.  Thanks!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>

#include "IndexCompare.h"

using namespace std;

template <class ForwardIterator, class T>
void iota(ForwardIterator first, ForwardIterator last, T value) {
     while (first != last) {
        *first++ = value++;
     }
}

const int MAX = 12;

int main() {
    int numbers[] = {37, 33, 29, 36, 32, 35, 39, 34, 30, 38, 31, 40};

    vector<int> vecNum(numbers, numbers + MAX);

    // Display original number array.
    cout << "--- initial numbers array ---" << endl;

    vector<int>::iterator iter = vecNum.begin();
    for (; iter != vecNum.end(); iter++ ) {
        cout << *iter << " ";
    }
    cout << "\n";

    vector<int> indices( vecNum.size() );

    // fill indices array
    cout << "\n--- invoke 'iota' on indices array ---";
    iota( indices.begin(), indices.end(), 0 );

    // Display original indices array.
    cout << "\n linear indices array: ";
    vector<int>::iterator iterIdx = indices.begin();
    for (; iterIdx != indices.end(); iterIdx++ ) {
        cout << *iterIdx << " ";
    }
    cout << "\n";

    // sort indices array
    cout << "\n--- invoke 'Sort' on indices based on number array ---";
    sort(indices.begin(), indices.end(),
          IndexCompare<vector<int>::iterator>(vecNum.begin(),vecNum.end()));

    // Display sorted indices array
    cout << "\n Sorted indices array: ";
    for (iterIdx = indices.begin(); iterIdx != indices.end(); iterIdx++ ) {
        cout << *iterIdx << " ";
    }
    cout << "\n";

    cout << "\n--- Run check on number array indexed normally ---";
    // Display original numbers array.
    cout << "\n replay numbers array: ";
    iter = vecNum.begin();
    for (; iter != vecNum.end(); iter++ ) {
        cout << *iter << " ";
    }
    cout << "\n";

    cout << "\n--- Run check on number array indexed with sorted indices ---";
    // Print original nums array indirectly through indices.
    cout << "\n number array via indices: ";
    for (int index = 0; index < vecNum.size(); index++ )
        cout << vecNum[indices[index]] << " ";
    cout << "\n";

    getchar();

    return 0;
}

// IndexCompare.h - interface for IndexCompare class template
#ifndef _INDEXCOMPARE_H_
#define _INDEXCOMPARE_H_
#pragma once

template <class random_iterator>
class IndexCompare {
public:
    IndexCompare(random_iterator begin, random_iterator end)
        : begin(begin), end(end) {}

    ~IndexCompare() {}

    bool operator() (unsigned int first, unsigned int second) {
            return (*(begin + first) < *(begin + second));

    }

private:
    random_iterator begin;
    random_iterator end;
};

#endif
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure I will be able to explain this correctly. Here is my try:

(1). `vector<int> indices( vecNum.size() );`

You are creating a vector to hold the indexes for the elements in vector `vecNum`. Obviously the number of elements in this vector is same as number of elements in `vecNum`.

(2). `iota( indices.begin(), indices.end(), 0 );`

Initializing the `indices` with values from `0 - vecNum.size() - 1`

(3).

```
sort(indices.begin(), indices.end(),
              IndexCompare<vector<int>::iterator>(vecNum.begin(),vecNum.end()));
```

For each element in the `indices` vector invoke the functor `IndexCompare`. This functor in its `operator()` gets the value from the `vecNum` vector corresponding to the given index position. So basically you are sorting the `indices` vector (not `vecNum`) based on the values in `vecNum`. Hence the `vecNum` remains unaffected and `indices` gets sorted based on the values from `vecNum`.

To make it more clearer (I hope), the initial state of the indices vector will be say:
indices = 0,1,2
and vecNum = 20,10,30

Now you are calling `std::sort` on this with your own functor. So to determine whether 0 is less than 1 `sort` algorithm will use your functor. Inside the functor you are determinng whether 0 < 1 using the logic whether vecNum[0] (i.e. 20) < vecNum[1] (i.e. 10). So the sorted out put will be indices = 1,0,2.